# How to select sentences similar to my sentence by crawling entire website?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, word2vec, doc2vec

If I give a sentence how to return all the similar sentences to it?
For example:
How much time will interview take?
The similar sentences should be
1.How long the interview lasts.
2.Duration of the interview.

How to do this?
One method I am thinking of is crawling the faq pages of 30 to 40 company career websites and embed the questions using doc2vec and I'll keep all the similar vectors in a cluster.

Is there a better method than this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the output from that will be random. Why not train it manually on a couple of dozen inputs like that. The results could quickl be pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have word-vectors – either generic one reused from elsewhere, or (better) some trained our your textual domain - you can also use "Word Mover's Distance" (WMD) to assess the similarity of sentences (or other short texts). Some demos show it does a really good job of ranking sentences by similar meaning, even if using very different word.

However, note that WMD is relatively expensive to calculate, compared to the simple vector-distances of methods which give each text a single vector like `Doc2Vec`. So, it may only be practical on smaller sets-of-texts, or if lots of computational power can be dedicated, or if extra first-pass optimizations limit the number of pairwise WMD calculations to make.

(There's also another metric that might approach WMD performance more cheaply, called 'Soft Cosine Similarity'. Both WMD and soft-cosine-similarity calculations are available in recent versions of the Python gensim package, but they aren't yet fully optimized nor best practices clearly described.)